# use grid.arrange over multiple pages or marrangeGrob with a layout_matrix

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, r-grid

i want to arrange plots with the following layout_matrix over multiple pages.

[image]

## rep. e.g.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

layout <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4),
                    c(1,2,3,4),
                    c(1,2,3,4),
                    c(5,5,5,5))
p <- list()
for(i in 1:15) {
    ifelse(i %% 5 > 0,
        p[[i]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(paste("plot:",i)),
        p[[i]] <- tableGrob(mtcars[5:7,],rows = NULL)
    )
}
```

if i have only one page: (easy)

```
grid.arrange(grobs=p[1:5],layout_matrix=layout)
```

if i want multiple pages: (i loose all my pattern)

```
marrangeGrob(grobs=p,nrow=4,ncol=2)
```

## pls help me with a general solution to have a layout_matrix on multiple pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this seems to work,

```
marrangeGrob(grobs=p, nrow=1, ncol=5, layout_matrix=layout)
```

(admittedly by chance)

`marrangeGrob` is just a thin wrapper around a for loop and grid.arrange, so in case you need something more refined than this lucky workaround you should probably modify the code to your needs.

Comment: Somehow works perfectly in that case. Thanks for sharing

Comment: tested it with couple different and more complex layouts including NA fields. Works all the time! Thats a real solution.

Comment: oh lord! thank you! This is the only solution that works. I was trying so long with facet_wrap_paginate, but it would keep overwriting the 1st page

Answer (score 1):

Made my own function, that makes multiple `grid.arrange` files with layout and then `marrangeGrob` it into a multipage object.

```
m.grid.arrange <- function(p,topnames,layMat) {
    pdf(file = NULL) #invisible
    plotsPerPage <- length(unique(na.omit(c(layMat))))

    ml <- lapply(1:ceiling(length(p)/plotsPerPage), function(page_IND){
        ind <- (1+((page_IND-1)*plotsPerPage)):(page_IND*plotsPerPage)
        grid.arrange(grobs = p[ind], layout_matrix = layMat,top=topnames[page_IND])
    })

    return(marrangeGrob(grobs=ml,nrow=1,ncol=1,top=NULL))
    dev.off() #invisible
}
```

Then use:

```
ml <- m.grid.arrange(p=p,topnames=c("1 label","2 label","3 label"),layMat = layout)
ggsave("gridMeHard.pdf",width = 297, height =  210, units = "mm", ml)
```